# PHP error in sql syntaxis

Tags: php, sql

No se que hacer. Me sale este error al ingresar digitos en el formulario:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your
> SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near 'selct * from ingredientes
> where NOMBRE=e and ID_TACOS=e' at line 1 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\cuerpo\control.php:10 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\cuerpo\control.php(10):
> mysqli->query('selct * from in...') #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\cuerpo\formulario.php(10):
> include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\cuerpo\control.php on line 10

```
if(!empty($_POST["ing"])){
    if (empty($_POST["u"]) and empty ($_POST["p"])){
        echo"CAMPO OBLIGATORIO";
    } else {
        $usuario=$_POST["u"];
        $clave=$_POST["p"];
        $sql=$con->query("SELECT * FROM ingredientes WHERE NOMBRE='$usuario' 
        AND ID_TACOS='$clave' ");
        if ($datos=$sql->fetch_object()) {
            header("location:../index.html");
        } else {
            echo"USUARIO NO EXISTE";
        }           
    }   
}
```

Comment: Evita utilizar imágenes ya que no todos pueden verlas, agrega tu código con el formato correspondiente para que algún colaborador pueda replicarlo y ayudarte mejor, veo que eres nuevo, date una vuelta por el [tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [ask].

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: El cacho de código que intentas mostrar **no se corresponde con el error que muestras**.  Si te fijas en el error pone esto:  `'selct * from ingredientes where NOMBRE=e and ID_TACOS=e'`  y en tu código no detecto el **selct** en ninguna parte.  Además en tu código estas entrecomillando los valores (correctamente) pero en el error no.  Por lo tanto busca esa consulta en otra parte y arréglala, pues donde estás mirando no es.

Comment: Bueno, de hecho el error ya te indica que es la línea 10 del archivo `C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\cuerpo\control.php`, por lo tanto vete a ese archivo y revisa de nuevo la consulta, y si ya la has arreglado ejecútala de nuevo y si te vuelve a dar error nos lo pegas de nuevo, pues será otro, y no el que has puesto ahora.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿esto que es?  `if ($datos=$sql=fetch_object())`... fijate bien lo que escribes, pues parece que tienes muchos fallos de sintaxis, y en programación la sintaxis es muy estricta y no se debe escribir sin repasar bien las cosas.

Comment: apenas estoy empezando en la programación y me guié por un vídeo lo que trato de hacer es un formulario de inicio de sesión, cuando respondo los campos de mi formulario y los envió me da ese error. Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: ¿Pero ya lo tienes arreglado?  ¿Has ido a la linea 10 del archivo `C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\cuerpo\control.php` y has encontrado la consulta errónea?

Comment: el código que subí es el de ese archivo, aun no entiendo cual podría ser el error

Comment: Pues no lo es a todas luces.  Ejecútalo de nuevo porque **no se corresponde** el error con el código que vemos en la pregunta.  En la pregunta tu código **parece correcto**, pero en el mensaje de error, aunque esté en inglés, salen otras cosas que no se parecen en nada a lo que nos pones en la pregunta. Fíjate que en el error pone **selct** (cuando tu en la pregunta pones bien **SELECT**). En el error pone **mysqli->query('selct * from** cuando en la pregunta has puesto **$sql=$con->query("SELECT * FROM**.  Por lo tanto **no es lo mismo** y debes asegurarte que no te equivocas de archivo.

Comment: Lo he resuelto, tenia duplicado un archivo y en la pagina se abría el que estaba mal. Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda

Comment: ya me parecia a mi... venga, borra la pregunta pues es un fallo que no se puede reproducir y si no la borras tu la borrarán los moderadores con el tiempo, y así les facilitas el trabajo.  Gracias!  Saludos!